# Cannot clone BoxHelper

Tags: three.js

In version r71 I could clone BoxHelper meshes.
When I upgrade to r72 or r73, anytime I try to clone a BoxHelper or any object containing a BoxHelper I get the following exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: object.updateMatrixWorld is not a function
```

You can replicate this by making the following change to the example code in "webgl_helpers.html"

Change line 73 from:

```
scene.add( new THREE.BoxHelper( mesh ) );
```

To:

```
var helper = new THREE.BoxHelper( mesh );
var helper1 = helper.clone();
scene.add( helper1 );
```

Is there a workaround?

Comment: That is a bug. Would you mind filing a three.js bug report?

Comment: @WestLangley just did. Issue #7824